# Issues when obtaining RMSE and R2 from predictions on test data

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a training data (train.dat) and test data (test.dat). I would like to run my linear regression, elastic, tree and random forest model on the test data after training it on the training data.

From there, I would like to get the RMSE and R2 to observe the predictive accuracy of the model. However, I have 2 issues:

1. When I train my random forest model on test data, I get the error: Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : missing values in newdata. Other models are fine
2. I can only extract the RMSE and R2 values for my tree model, while the other models return NAs. A screenshot is below
   [image]

Can anyone tell me what has gone wrong with my code?

My code:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(10345678)

tr.Control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 5,
                           classProbs = FALSE,
                            )

lm7 <- train(Lifeexp ~ . + Govthealth*Privhealth, 
             data = train.dat, 
                 method = 'lm', 
                 trControl = tr.Control,
                preProc = c("center", "scale")
                )

alpha.vec <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
lambda.vec2 <- seq(0, 30, length.out = 50)
elastic.grid <- expand.grid(alpha = alpha.vec, lambda = lambda.vec2)
elastic4 <- train(Lifeexp ~ ., data = train.dat, 
                 method = 'glmnet', 
                 trControl = tr.Control,
                 verbose = FALSE,
                tuneGrid = elastic.grid,
                preProc = c("center", "scale")
                )

cp.vec <- seq(10^-4, 0.1, length.out = 50 )
tree2 <- train(Lifeexp ~ ., data = train.dat
                 , trControl = tr.Control
                 , method = "rpart"
                 , preProcess = c("center", "scale")
                 , tuneGrid = expand.grid(cp = cp.vec)
                 )

rf1 <- train(
  Lifeexp ~ .,
  data = train.dat,
  method = "rf",
  trControl = tr.Control ,
  preProc = c("center", "scale"),  
  ntree = 1000,
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = seq(1, ncol(train.dat)-1)
                         )
)

regression.pred <- predict(lm7, newdata = test.dat, na.action = na.pass, type = "raw")
elastic.pred <- predict(elastic4, newdata = test.dat, na.action = na.pass, type = "raw")
tree.pred <- predict(tree2, newdata = test.dat, na.action = na.pass, type = "raw")
rf.pred <- predict(rf1, newdata = test.dat, na.action = na.pass, type = "raw")

test.statistics <- data.frame(
  RMSE.regression = RMSE(regression.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  Rsquare.regression = R2(regression.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  RMSE.el = RMSE(elastic.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  Rsquare.el = R2(elastic.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  RMSE.tree = RMSE(tree.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp), 
  Rsquare.tree = R2(tree.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp)
)

test.statistics
```

train.dat:

```
structure(list(GDP = c(402.1030419, 442.2030419, 543.3030419, 
520.8966027, 254.2432569, 124.4608003, 341.5541149, 772.3135303, 
478.6685897, 191.8789042, 592.4010975, 1033.912431, 138.4288795, 
622.4988457, 642.7767443, 317.3893069, 269.8711377, 709.5819646, 
585.07655, 780.190201, 3122.362815, 3893.596078, 1166.610276, 
1674.825261, 3690.113268, 4241.788782, 2441.741991, 4043.662051, 
9040.566251, 963.8417858, 2234.579866, 10330.61561, 1944.137621, 
2136.440243, 567.5286729, 567.930736, 2292.445156, 2028.18197, 
371.6785662, 519.5343268, 987.409723, 1482.403063, 1196.586858, 
1955.588006, 6941.235848, 1038.90854, 3102.713363, 3139.966054, 
3032.427138, 7328.615629, 869.6965166, 2799.648876, 617.2304355, 
1126.683318, 4094.362119, 7708.100996, 10385.96443, 11683.94962, 
718.1878292, 3243.231125, 3100.280468, 11286.24302, 8920.762105, 
201.4671636, 785.5022829, 1510.324871, 1831.001912, 8141.913127, 
12027.36588, 6967.24523, 7691.345097, 3233.295943, 367.5566093, 
1357.563719, 1489.876911, 977.2736357, 1508.942737, 2007.736363, 
5076.342992, 7273.563207, 948.3318545, 2146.996385, 95.18825018, 
390.0933261, 2566.59695, 52022.1256, 57373.68668, 19095.467, 
28149.87001, 39435.8399, 20600.37525, 23041.53473, 44141.87814, 
47518.63604, 24190.24962, 46232.98962, 26891.44645, 61350.34791, 
28364.64508, 50152.34014, 22303.96133, 23635.92922, 41531.9342, 
47603.02763, 9600.18513, 12042.95373, 26917.75898, 20324.25356, 
20087.59199, 36000.52012, 25423.07201, 32018.06325, 43024.92384, 
73191.11632, 12663.36453, 30693.59308, 18440.37852, 38577.38166, 
33994.40657, 21290.86038, 50950.03434, 53024.05921, 13663.02162, 
13641.10272, 41945.33167, 1731.209509, 4492.727604, 11861.75616, 
47236.96023, 23509.54339, 26123.97387, 74605.77451), Health = c(22.23474948, 
36.44474948, 45.58774948, 46.38774948, 3.333203815, 5.359203815, 
16.69390488, 19.46990488, 33.22835541, 5.300580788, 29.97179604, 
33.59179604, 5.971383095, 62.66848373, 67.22848373, 8.23568, 
14.98141193, 32.6487999, 10.22661548, 16.19961548, 92.18703461, 
98.65987461, 143.7665911, 159.7515106, 308.6578979, 402.5568979, 
99.5689502, 111.4155502, 292.8907166, 198.2263198, 221.1403198, 
705.336568, 176.6524443, 200.7054443, 12.56211728, 17.72411728, 
76.7208786, 98.4562786, 9.55682529, 16.01162529, 26.5686245, 
33.565445, 69.66563616, 89.45643616, 275.2236792, 32.77552414, 
122.5689168, 198.7124574, 221.7829742, 539.567627, 43.70681763, 
108.6149597, 33.2254878, 42.36598, 60.2569, 705.1993408, 891.1377563, 
992.5689563, 31.84200096, 77.2356478, 277.45864, 891.7641602, 
932.325129, 15.23564, 54.30473709, 74.231488, 200.564125, 665.2514038, 
755.36985, 384.9183044, 445.20158, 262.5267029, 11.56898, 45.25077438, 
109.0749969, 122.02145, 42.568412, 62.25963211, 172.0576935, 
200.562134, 91.17743683, 120.236549, 11.23587, 18.82835197, 99.23568, 
4952.777344, 5236.3654, 1101.36589, 1674.2854, 3309.480957, 1654.5687, 
1845.321045, 4449.542969, 5000.36545, 1998.634277, 6054.23658, 
1900.2356, 7025.36987, 1000.5689, 5036.2356, 1233.36545, 2334.651855, 
4597.244629, 5698.2547, 1500.3698, 2000.23564, 2573.740234, 3002.36547, 
1520.453613, 3214.546387, 1569.3254, 2873.848145, 3644.802734, 
4587.235478, 1122.02145, 2211.019043, 462.5890808, 1061.365601, 
1256.56897, 1987.2145, 5186.632813, 6547.2356, 990.32658, 1053.891602, 
4201.3698, 122.02145, 238.0044861, 712.2356, 1513.565918, 2015.18042, 
2985.23, 8021.80957), Govthealth = c(1.25689, 2.032658, 2.495758057, 
2.965478, 1.985478, 2.209019899, 2.882325411, 3.21458, 7.3134408, 
1.032568, 5.433434963, 7.235478, 1.239725351, 8.535984039, 10.323589, 
1.236589, 3.562868595, 4.673761368, 2.32547, 4.648055553, 23.70949936, 
33.235687, 51025478, 71.8605423, 205.9026794, 295.2356, 31.2587, 
51.99817276, 154.70401, 56.32588, 73.30036926, 399.23568, 66.3265, 
99.82849121, 2.23568, 3.246135235, 10.43734169, 15.235478, 3.569877, 
5.623521328, 5.849419594, 8.32665, 35.3654457, 44.96020508, 195.3657, 
14.55177689, 35.235698, 61.02356, 81.59127045, 284.7705994, 23.43979454, 
43.92045593, 22.36587, 30.42416763, 181.3415375, 385.9675598, 
576.0806274, 602.3258, 25.36730576, 66.235687, 92.2147, 401.4833984, 
502.3698, 2.0214578, 10.70767879, 15.36987, 112.3698, 481.0765686, 
502.36987, 226.7909851, 300.65478, 55.95266342, 2.36547, 11.85855961, 
35.50076675, 45.235698, 25.36954, 34.36005783, 126.9312592, 156.3257, 
23.53768349, 39.235687, 4.235687, 6.570708275, 45.36987, 3399.406006, 
4500.321547, 990.36547, 1368.160278, 2804.857178, 1000.365, 1375.334717, 
3458.573975, 4120.325, 1456.037842, 4100.368, 1500.36578, 6925.325445, 
990.58795, 4125.25658, 998.25998, 1827.566895, 3482.541016, 4800.3256, 
989.325, 1254.325, 1756.99939, 1998.23569, 1104.429321, 2521.927002, 
1800.3256, 2315.543701, 2931.431641, 331.0256, 548.32, 1388.55896, 
351.3133545, 898.4367065, 997.02145, 956.32547, 3488.651855, 
4400.23556, 558.36987, 785.0509033, 3000.3658, 100.36987, 162.3498688, 
162.365, 543.0645752, 1458.283813, 2000.3694, 2495.23877), Privhealth = c(14.3698, 
25.36698, 36.01279831, 49.36875, 1.23569, 2.278559208, 8.061329842, 
10.3658, 5.059076786, 3.25698, 20.38587761, 30.65877, 4.726452827, 
22.79703331, 32.65878, 6.32589, 10.38636589, 19.33849907, 8.326589, 
11.07592678, 67.27728271, 74.23658, 63.235698, 83.74517059, 88.83229828, 
96.32568, 49.32658, 59.41738892, 138.1631165, 100.23564, 147.8399658, 
300.23568, 71.02584, 90.6206665, 8.365984, 11.47062778, 61.48280716, 
74.254785, 7.235647, 10.26313496, 19.40570831, 23.65879, 33.25478, 
44.17641068, 189.32658, 17.06592751, 75.325689, 89.32658, 136.7345276, 
238.6507721, 19.86775017, 63.43461227, 7.325478, 19.23568, 25.321547, 
319.0157471, 311.9694214, 442.03695, 3.889117956, 15.3654, 115.02365, 
488.0875244, 552.0325698, 10.3658, 36.04922485, 45.362154, 45.23548, 
182.7733917, 202.3654, 142.2067719, 202.325, 197.0276337, 9.32658, 
32.95304871, 70.28269196, 90.3256, 15.021457, 27.89465141, 44.9021492, 
60.32568, 43.03323364, 60.325845, 8.325698, 11.45799065, 60.32568, 
1553.358765, 2330.2354, 201.0214578, 305.5347595, 503.7982178, 
301.23565, 469.9864197, 990.9689331, 1200.36987, 542.5964966, 
1823.021457, 312.0215478, 1100.32145, 301.02145, 1100.3256, 320.365478, 
507.0849609, 1114.720093, 2001.23548, 401.14567, 662.03214, 816.2644653, 
998.32546, 416.0243225, 692.6192017, 402.32564, 558.3044434, 
713.3709106, 998.32658, 302.0214, 793.8995972, 111.2757187, 162.9289398, 
212.3657, 442.32598, 1698.060913, 2226.32568, 145.2365, 268.8859863, 
902.32568, 42.36587, 75.64861298, 332.65478, 970.5014648, 556.8964233, 
700.32658, 5526.447266), Population = c(12412308L, 20779953L, 
29185507L, 37172386L, 47887865L, 66224804L, 87639964L, 109224559L, 
14539612L, 18905478L, 27013212L, 28087871L, 6216341L, 32428167L, 
42723139L, 8449913L, 10946445L, 15049353L, 181413402L, 211513823L, 
241834215L, 267663435L, 3565890L, 5122493L, 7261539L, 9956011L, 
18029824L, 23194257L, 28208035L, 223158L, 279398L, 515696L, 1432905L, 
1794571L, 95212450L, 122283850L, 158503197L, 195874740L, 107647921L, 
142343578L, 179424641L, 212215030L, 22071433L, 26459944L, 31989256L, 
77991755L, 106651922L, 36800509L, 44967708L, 51216964L, 18777601L, 
20261737L, 3286542L, 3089027L, 2913021L, 36870787L, 40788453L, 
44494502L, 591021L, 754394L, 149003223L, 195713635L, 209469333L, 
8975597L, 14312212L, 16249798L, 3119433L, 4577378L, 4999441L, 
70878L, 71625L, 3786695L, 873277798L, 1234281170L, 34545013L, 
41801533L, 56558186L, 62952642L, 67195028L, 69428524L, 12697723L, 
14439018L, 67988862L, 79910412L, 95540395L, 22031750L, 24982688L, 
57247586L, 58892514L, 62766365L, 9967379L, 10251250L, 10895586L, 
11433256L, 30685730L, 37057765L, 5140939L, 5793636L, 4986431L, 
5515525L, 79433029L, 82211508L, 81776930L, 82905782L, 10196792L, 
10805808L, 11121341L, 10731726L, 56942108L, 59277417L, 254826L, 
281205L, 318041L, 352721L, 4660000L, 7623600L, 2045123L, 2991884L, 
4137309L, 14951510L, 16615394L, 17231624L, 3329800L, 3857700L, 
4841000L, 38110782L, 38258629L, 3047132L, 5076732L, 2048583L, 
2073894L, 7824909L), Lifeexp = c(50.331, 55.841, 61.028, 64.486, 
47.099, 51.941, 61.627, 66.24, 55.564, 54.404, 67.611, 70.478, 
61.974, 57.099, 62.973, 45.746, 48.069, 55.251, 62.32, 65.772, 
69.205, 71.509, 69.872, 71.73, 73.428, 74.405, 70.865, 72.594, 
74.493, 61.529, 70.173, 78.627, 61.608, 52.192, 45.9, 46.267, 
50.896, 54.332, 60.1, 62.82, 65.264, 67.114, 66.165, 71.111, 
76.516, 68.793, 71.095, 63.307, 56.048, 57.669, 71.333, 75.439, 
71.836, 73.955, 76.562, 73.576, 75.278, 76.52, 60.884, 71.46, 
66.343, 73.619, 75.672, 53.595, 66.56, 69.57, 75.654, 78.769, 
80.095, 74.619, 77.672, 71.46, 57.865, 66.693, 62.764, 65.095, 
70.248, 70.623, 74.184, 76.931, 50.64, 61.195, 70.551, 73.025, 
75.317, 81.69512195, 82.74878049, 75.8804878, 77.74146341, 80.40243902, 
76.05195122, 77.72195122, 80.18292683, 81.59512195, 79.13658537, 
81.94878049, 74.80536585, 81.35121951, 74.81317073, 81.83414634, 
75.2277561, 77.92682927, 79.98780488, 80.99268293, 76.93902439, 
77.88780488, 80.38780488, 81.28780488, 79.77804878, 82.03658537, 
78.03634146, 79.65365854, 81.89756098, 82.66097561, 76.60731707, 
81.60243902, 73.142, 74.358, 75.398, 76.87804878, 80.70243902, 
81.76097561, 75.37804878, 78.63658537, 81.85853659, 70.8902439, 
73.74878049, 75.29512195, 81.54146341, 79.42195122, 81.02926829, 
82.24634146), Govted = c(1.23568, 2.31245, 3.47945, 5.32658, 
2.365, 3.98311, 4.49659, 6.32547, 3.5398, 1.023568, 3.63172, 
5.16365, 2.32871, 2.38901, 2.52076, 1.23568, 2.97156, 3.34389, 
0.984578, 1.36589, 2.81228, 4.326587, 1.2365897, 1.9654789, 2.3658, 
3.58851, 3.23568, 5.97161, 4.96645, 1.23568, 3.21548, 6.32547, 
2.32657, 6.99139, 1.32658, 2.012457, 3.214587, 4.235687, 2.51681, 
1.83782, 2.28687, 3.9854587, 2.36587, 3.22803, 3.71993, 3.26766, 
5.32568, 5.12579, 5.44358, 5.72174, 2.36578, 1.71774, 2.3265, 
3.43017, 2.65897, 4.58031, 5.01971, 6.32658, 5.51379, 6.64043, 
2.36587, 5.6488, 6.32658, 1.235687, 1.53379, 2.16286, 3.24578, 
6.63445, 7.02824, 2.36578, 3.325478, 3.215487, 3.23568, 3.37769, 
2.32657, 3.23654, 3.323568, 5.25346, 3.50844, 5.32658, 1.54406, 
4.60449, 3.326589, 4.235478, 4.17277, 5.55006, 6.32365, 4.05552, 
4.06533, 5.74164, 4.021547, 5.32658, 6.40799, 6.9874564, 5.442, 
6.32658, 7.32658, 8.9854587, 5.33591, 7.32658, 3.0215478, 3.21547, 
4.91368, 6.3265, 2.04608, 3.23019, 4.32658, 5.023658, 4.29886, 
4.35239, 4.25224, 6.44717, 6.97848, 7.235689, 5.43073, 5.54157, 
2.985467, 3.124578, 3.32652, 5.22879, 5.48909, 4.236587, 5.321457, 
6.323658, 7.5698745, 3.26587, 4.9936, 2.325647, 3.08044, 5.56251, 
5.965871, 4.92605)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 70L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 82L, 
84L, 85L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 99L, 100L, 
103L, 105L, 107L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 119L, 120L, 
121L, 122L, 124L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 
136L, 138L, 140L, 141L, 144L, 145L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 
153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 158L, 159L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
167L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 180L, 181L, 
182L, 185L, 187L, 191L, 192L, 195L), class = "data.frame")
```

Test.dat:

```
structure(list(GDP = c(199.9863423, 156.3857186, 389.3980332, 
229.4902871, 497.6320261, 749.552711, 826.6215305, 248.0293672, 
261.8689977, 899.6599081, 11373.233, 7076.662423, 5324.61704, 
5931.453886, 5082.354757, 715.9137121, 2124.05677, 6374.028196, 
463.6186318, 4102.48135, 5268.848504, 4333.482973, 564.7796095, 
2258.183141, 3749.75325, 302.5771636, 3772.870012, 2860.43156, 
4787.780171, 1614.640122, 749.9085236, 4717.143026, 443.3141934, 
2009.978857, 483.952592, 366.1728076, 841.9729898, 563.0577411, 
1317.890706, 18211.27459, 21679.24784, 42943.90227, 21448.36196, 
47450.31847, 30743.54768, 58041.39844, 24285.46682, 46459.97325, 
20825.78421, 34483.204, 21043.57493, 41715.02928, 8794.631229, 
26149.41108, 33692.01083, 12599.53358, 15420.91116, 23852.32703, 
64581.94402, 9107.477079, 10201.30354, 38428.3855, 37868.296, 
82796.54716), Health = c(6.22435541, 8.909747124, 39.22274712, 
8.625580788, 4.22284155, 42.34384155, 47.44484155, 10.74555809, 
18.80055809, 45.32365, 324.6654166, 602.659668, 504.5536499, 
594.8854499, 239.3392792, 22.55662414, 91.84031677, 624.335527, 
30.56891763, 128.3355597, 74.23569, 505.4589408, 22.23569, 69.80043793, 
311.6526794, 19.73552704, 251.0935822, 211.589745, 250.7455292, 
35.25698, 47.90106964, 292.54782, 18.56432343, 70.5685123, 10.56888, 
17.38329887, 50.66987, 75.201547, 78.18682861, 1022.5487, 1632.427612, 
4002.325, 1452.369, 5044.135254, 2496.047119, 6011.536621, 1655.866211, 
4099.587891, 1125.365, 4400.325, 1496.87854, 3000.23568, 336.2356, 
2023.143677, 3216.223633, 809.1994019, 956.21547, 820.6981812, 
1989.235, 446.3265, 796.6470337, 2985.12, 3737.802979, 9658.23
), Govthealth = c(2.65987, 3.350677967, 8.32365, 1.337858081, 
0.235689, 8.714180946, 11.02365, 2.356894, 4.656533241, 5.958777, 
198.23568, 319.1759033, 207.0215302, 302.654789, 123.2336197, 
9.32658, 29.2992878, 300.5689, 12.02589, 52.658912, 22.03256, 
222.325689, 16.3258, 50.29269791, 129.758316, 3.900079966, 163.0175018, 
102.369, 156.8104706, 4.36987, 5.465222836, 75.36987, 3.839128733, 
14.32589, 3.25478, 5.880064487, 12.36547, 18.02584, 30.97570801, 
990.365478, 1116.231445, 3201.0245, 996.598723, 3721.796387, 
2074.39917, 5042.459961, 1229.708252, 3167.418213, 889.32658, 
3698.23598, 944.5585938, 1998.02365, 200.365778, 1396.733398, 
2517.370117, 577.3640747, 662.32589, 298.1834717, 702.369, 456.325, 
568.7339478, 889.36547, 1045.900513, 3987.3654), Privhealth = c(1.36589, 
1.832908154, 7.325698, 5.431494236, 2.36589, 29.85413742, 35.3698, 
4.23568, 8.9836483, 22.3658, 152.36589, 263.3545532, 225.5363922, 
301.325478, 111.575592, 10.23568, 60.89479446, 336.02145, 12.36587, 
75.36987, 34.3265, 223.02145, 2.0215478, 11.81901455, 180.9026947, 
15.41190529, 85.28456879, 45.321478, 86.49634552, 25.36987, 39.00668716, 
220.32145, 14.22738075, 49.326545, 7.02145, 11.50323391, 20.36587, 
33.021456, 45.45627975, 400.23568, 516.1798096, NA, 400.32547, 
1322.338745, 421.6481018, 969.076416, 426.0691833, 931.8737793, 
302.1245, 886.02154, 517.4750366, 889.32547, 90.3256, 626.4102173, 
698.8658447, 231.8352966, 301.0324, 522.5147705, 1236.021458, 
117.3658, 227.9130707, 1965.3256, 2691.985107, 6600.3256), Population = c(9404500L, 
11148758L, 18143315L, 23941110L, 5283814L, 7527394L, 9100837L, 
17354392L, 23650172L, 19077690L, 31528585L, 365734L, 2118874L, 
2448255L, 29027674L, 61895160L, 93966780L, 57779622L, 17325773L, 
21670000L, 2866376L, 32618651L, 530804L, 685503L, 174790340L, 
12155239L, 3962372L, 70419L, 69650L, 4802000L, 4077131L, 3726549L, 
1056575549L, 1352617328L, 20147590L, 27275015L, 10432421L, 11881477L, 
87967651L, 17065100L, 19153000L, 66460344L, 27691138L, 34004889L, 
5339616L, 5547683L, 5176209L, 5363352L, 56719240L, 60421760L, 
6289000L, 8882800L, 2095344L, 15925513L, 4350700L, 38042794L, 
37974750L, 4027887L, 5638676L, 1998161L, 1988925L, 6715519L, 
7184250L, 8513227L), Lifeexp = c(46.096, 45.09, 63.798, 62.288, 
58.824, 68.736, 70.879, 45.853, 46.229, 58.893, 75.997, 75.905, 
56.665, 63.373, 74.41, 66.366, 69.823, 63.857, 69.509, 76.812, 
78.458, 71.594, 52.878, 68.384, 70.116, 58.432, 77.452, 66.843, 
71.116, 70.386, 69.902, 73.6, 62.505, 69.416, 55.5, 58.472, 58.1, 
44.649, 74.837, 76.99463415, 79.23414634, 81.35609756, 77.42195122, 
81.24634146, 76.59268293, 79.1, 77.46585366, 79.87073171, 76.97073171, 
82.94634146, 78.95365854, 82.80243902, 72.15, 77.98780488, 80.70243902, 
76.24634146, 77.75365854, 77.95121951, 83.14634146, 73.20487805, 
75.41219512, 77.24243902, 79.6804878, 83.55121951), Govted = c(3.27054, 
5.24797, 4.71484, 2.97515, 1.36587, 4.00675, 6.32547, 1.023658, 
2.46167, 4.32658, 4.53477, 4.11747, 8.34961, 10.23547, 2.8673, 
2.36587, 5.326545, 6.15899, 2.41093, 2.11189, 2.46866, 1.06738, 
3.21547, 4.02447, 3.94893, 1.65599, 4.68696, 1.856231, 2.032145, 
1.56897, 2.18109, 4.236587, 4.32479, 5.326587, 0.36589, 1.01218, 
1.45426, 2.36589, 5.13722, 4.6764, 4.89147, 7.3265, 5.99199, 
5.36993, 8.08434, 8.55955, 5.71688, 6.54071, 3.325687, 5.32658, 
6.12262, 6.32658, 1.326587, 4.58512, 7.00241, 5.06843, 6.32547, 
3.3213, 5.32658, 3.32365, 4.32657, 4.52294, 4.7814, 5.9658745
)), row.names = c(9L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
28L, 40L, 43L, 47L, 48L, 59L, 61L, 63L, 68L, 69L, 72L, 76L, 77L, 
81L, 83L, 86L, 90L, 94L, 97L, 98L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 106L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 117L, 118L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 132L, 137L, 139L, 142L, 
143L, 146L, 147L, 157L, 160L, 166L, 168L, 169L, 174L, 179L, 183L, 
184L, 186L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 193L, 194L, 196L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
#Remove the NA from the data freme
test.dat <- na.omit(test.dat)

regression.pred <- predict(lm7, newdata = test.dat, type = "raw")
elastic.pred <- predict(elastic4, newdata = test.dat, type = "raw")
tree.pred <- predict(tree2, newdata = test.dat, type = "raw")
rf.pred <- predict(rf1, newdata = test.dat, type = "raw")

test.statistics <- data.frame(
  RMSE.regression = RMSE(regression.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  Rsquare.regression = R2(regression.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  RMSE.el = RMSE(elastic.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  Rsquare.el = R2(elastic.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp),
  RMSE.tree = RMSE(tree.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp), 
  Rsquare.tree = R2(tree.pred, test.dat$Lifeexp)
)

test.statistics

#  RMSE.regression Rsquare.regression  RMSE.el Rsquare.el RMSE.tree Rsquare.tree
# 1        8.201072          0.3910896 8.115006  0.3984145  6.369994    0.6446954
```